# Get A record from DNS capture

Tags: awk, sed, dns

I am new to playing with regular expression, but wondering if we can have any regex for below captures. I want to see everything after "A" in the logs below.

```
  3   0.238497  x.x.x.x -> x.x.x.x DNS 101 Standard query 0xab5d  A servicesx.x.x.x
  6   0.241131 x.x.x.x -> x.x.x.x  DNS 117 Standard query response 0xab5d  A x.x.x.x
  7   0.407185  x.x.x.x -> x.x.x.x DNS 100 Standard query 0x7699  A vipservices-x.x.x.x
  8   0.409849 x.x.x.x -> x.x.x.x  DNS 116 Standard query response 0x7699  A x.x.x.x
  9   2.905559  x.x.x.x -> x.x.x.x DNS 101 Standard query 0x9c5d  A servicesx.x.x.x
 10   2.908308 x.x.x.x -> x.x.x.x  DNS 117 Standard query response 0x9c5d  A x.x.x.x
 11   3.261304  x.x.x.x -> x.x.x.x DNS 101 Standard query 0x9575  A servicesx.x.x.x
 12   3.263582 x.x.x.x -> x.x.x.x  DNS 117 Standard query response 0x9575  A x.x.x.x
 13   4.898380  x.x.x.x -> x.x.x.x DNS 101 Standard query 0x451a  A servicesx.x.x.x
 14   4.900842 x.x.x.x -> x.x.x.x  DNS 117 Standard query response 0x451a  A x.x.x.x
 15   5.406778  x.x.x.x -> x.x.x.x DNS 100 Standard query 0x4f52  A vipservices-x.x.x.x
```

I want output something like this.

```
A servicesx.x.x.x
A vipservices-x.x.x.x
A servicesx.x.x.x
```

Any lead would be appreciated.

Comment: this `grep -o 'A.*'` ??

Comment: @PS. Bingo. that's what I was after for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print everything followed by A including A.

```
grep -o 'A.*' inputFile
```

`grep` solution: using `-o` flag to print ONLY matching string.

```
grep -o 'A.*service.*' inputFile
A servicesx.x.x.x
A vipservices-x.x.x.x
A servicesx.x.x.x
A servicesx.x.x.x
A servicesx.x.x.x
A vipservices-x.x.x.x
```

`A.*service.*` : means A followed by zero or more characters followed by service followed by everything.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{if(match($NF,"service")!=0) print $(NF-1),$NF}' file
A servicesx.x.x.x
A vipservices-x.x.x.x
A servicesx.x.x.x
A servicesx.x.x.x
A servicesx.x.x.x
A vipservices-x.x.x.x
```

If the last field match the patterne`"service"`, then print `$(NF-1) & $NF`

Comment: I think you could also use search of string /string/ and comparison of that string with $NF too here.

Comment: Don't use a regexp comparison when a string comparison is needed (for robustness and efficiency). Using a string instead of regexp comparion function your code would be `awk '{if(index($NF,"service")!=0) print $(NF-1),$NF}' file` but of course there's no point embedding the condition inside of the action so you'd really write it as `awk 'index($NF,"service"){print $(NF-1),$NF}' file`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
awk '$NF ~ /services/{print $(NF-1),$NF}'   Input_file
```

checking if last field of line is having services string in it, if yes then printing the second last field and last field of that line.

Answer (score 0):

Robustly, portably, efficiently to print everything from `A` on you'd do:

```
awk '$(NF-1) == "A" { print $(NF-1}, $NF }' file
```

otherwise a regexp solution that at least is portable to all UNIX systems would be:

```
sed -n '/.*A/A/p' file
```